# Types of Streams based on Data Flow?

Tags: java, stream, java-io

Long Story Short:
How many types of Streams are there based on Data Flow in the java.io package?
Are they Byte Streams and Character Streams or Binary Streams and Character Streams?

Full Question:

https://youtu.be/v1_ATyL4CNQ?t=20m5s
Skip to 20:05
After watching this tutorial yesterday, I was left with the impression that there are 2 Types of Streams, based on Data Flow: BinaryStreams and CharacterStreams. Today after learning more about the topic, my new findings seem to contradict the old ones.

Most of the people on the internet divide the Streams into 2 types Byte Streams and Character Streams. However when searching oracle docs I found information about Binary Streams too, then I found information about Int, Double, Long Streams from the java.util.stream package.

I am sorry if I am asking a silly question, but I am really confused right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The naming is really confusing

The I/O streams (Byte Streams and Character Streams) are data streams are
***completely unrelated*** to the new Stream API (java.util.stream). So we are talking here about two differents things with the same name "**stream**".

**IO Streams** : used on Input/output operations reading the data from a resource (input), or writing the data to a resource (output).

**java.util.stream** :include Stream,IntStream,DoubleStream... Stream definition by Oracle documentation is a *sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations*.